# How to set value of array object property inside a promise in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, feathersjs

I am using [feathersjs](http://feathersjs.com) with [feathers-client](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-client) with VueJS and I get a `Cannot set property 'employees' of undefined` typeerror. This is my code:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="employee in employees">{{employee.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import feathers from 'feathers/client'
import socketio from 'feathers-socketio/client'
import hooks from 'feathers-hooks'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io('localhost:3030')
var app = feathers().configure(hooks())
                    .configure(socketio(socket))
                    .configure(authentication({ storage: window.localStorage }));

export default {
 data() {
   return {
     employees: []
   }
 },
 mounted() {
     app.authenticate().then(function(response) {
          app.service('users').find().then(function(users) {
            this.employees = users.data
          })
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
   }
}

</script>
```

And when I run it I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'employees' of undefined
```

in the console.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside function points to that function so

```
 mounted() {
         var self = this; //add this line
         app.authenticate().then(function(response) {
              app.service('users').find().then(function(users) {
                self.employees = users.data //change this to self
              })
            }, function(error) {
              console.log(error)
            })
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why haven't I thought that?

Comment: @FewFlyBy ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I did think of this and it's driving me crazy that I can't get it to work